# Android to MS Sql query

Tags: android, sql-server

my application was working fine but then i changed something and its not inserting records in the database. when ever i press the submit button it show me toast "Record not inserted"
here is the code

```
connect=connn.ConnHelper(username, password, db, ipaddress);
 if (connect == null){
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connection Unsuccessfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else {
//inserting records in database
 //is se nechy nechy
 try {
     st = connect.createStatement();
     String query = "insert into profiles(Name,City,Address,Speciality,Phone,CNIC,Picture,Status) values('" + name + "','" + city + "','" + add + "','"+spec+"','"+ph+"','"+cn+"','"+img+"','pending');";
     preStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);

     int k=preStatement.executeUpdate();
     if(k==1){
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Record Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Intent imageIntent = new Intent("com.androsoft.application.Profile");
         imageIntent.putExtra("Id",Cnic.getText().toString());
         startActivity(imageIntent);
     }
     else{
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Record Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Record Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

here its returning zero to k.
mydatabase entities are.

[database entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmAfC.png)

Comment: Is `add` is not a reserved keyword in android ?

Comment: I think "add" is address

Comment: Make sure you are committing the transaction

Comment: With WebApi existing.......why does anyone write an android app that talks directly to sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this application in debug mode, and get the String query value on runtime (like `insert into profiles(Name,City,Address,Speciality,Phone,CNIC,Picture,Status) value('dav','city','new york',null,'33','f');`, then try to execute the query directly in sql server. If there is no problem in your query so this is something in the connection to the data base or problem in the application.

Comment: So you have problem with your query? Maybe your value is not valid to the type? for example if you are trying to insert varchar data into int type.

Comment: i am using online sql server and there is a website also from where record can be inserted successfully but in application its not working with same values

Comment: Doe's this statement was successfully run on your app?  'st = connect.createStatement();'